# How to cutdown on the extra items if I have created a teams rather than communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, administration, team-sites

I have created a teams SharePoint site. The purpose of the site is actually for one way communication of the articles written by a few authors to be read by a large audience.

Accordingly I have setup a few users in the members group, and a large audience in the visitors group.

I understand this is more of a communication site use case, rather than teams site. Because this is a teams site, I have O365 group, mailbox, etc. Whereas I only need the SharePoint site.

Now since I do not want the extra items like mailbox, O365 group, what are my options to cut down on these? Can I delete the mailbox O365 group? Or is there a way I can switch my teams site to communication site?

Comment: Did you already add pages/data to this team site? Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the team site connected to M365 group to communication site. For more information, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/727371/how-to-change-a-team-site-into-a-communication-sit. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks you can place the above in an answer and I'll mark it as an answer. Could you also tell me if there is any negative impact of leaving the site as teams site in my scenario, so that I'm aware of any implications of this so that I can manage it.

Comment: Added answer below. There is no negative impact on using team site vs using communication site. You can also change the team site navigation to "Horizontal" orientation so that site navigation will look like communication site (at the top side instead of left hand side). Check: [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to convert a SharePoint team site connected with M365 group into a communication site.

Yes, you need to change the name and the URL of the team site to create a communication site (with the same name) and migrate data.

Check more information and detailed steps at: [How to change a team site into a communication site?](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/727371/how-to-change-a-team-site-into-a-communication-sit?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

**Related read**:

[Convert SharePoint team site to communication site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/converter-team-site-to-communication-site/m-p/2117011?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)